# Azure SignalR missing custom headers

Tags: azure, websocket, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

I am using **Azure** **SignalR** for my .NET project as Hub.

On the other side, I am using a React app as a client. In the script, I add some custom headers to the **HubConnectionBuilder** class. When the connection client<-> hub is being established, the headers are gone. The custom headers disappear when reaching the server so when I am trying to get some data from the headers in the **OnConnectedAsync** method on Hub side, it occurs they are not there.

Worth to mention:

- Everything works if as a client I am using a .NET app or Node script
- When using normal SignalR (not as an Azure resource) everything works again.
- It seems to work if forcing the React app to use long-pooling
- change the **Service Mode** in Azure SignalR resource
- add different headers in different ways
- use different server SignalR options

*Client (React) code:*

```
const connection= new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(HUB_URL, {
        accessTokenFactory: () => getToken(),
        headers: deviceId && {
            deviceId: deviceId
        }
    })
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .build();

connection.start()
```

*Hub Code*

```
 public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
   const string headerDeviceIdKey = "deviceId";

   var headers = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers;

   if (headers.ContainsKey(headerDeviceIdKey))
   {
       //...
   }
   return base.OnConnectedAsync();
}
```

Edit:

- v1.
  The .NET app is hosted on Azure but the issues appears the same when running the app loccaly iand being connected to Azure resources.

Comment: Is this locally ?  - any proxy / firewall in play ?

Comment: Please include your client and server side code

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Dictionary of headers sent with every HTTP request. **Sending headers in the browser doesn't work for** *WebSockets* or the *ServerSentEvents* stream.

Official document: [Configure additional options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=javascript#configure-additional-options)

**Reason**

1.[This is a limitation of the browser and not something SignalR can fix.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/1495#issuecomment-1238386753)

2.[SignalR typescript client fails to add custom headers](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37700)